# Azure databricks notebook missing Repo

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I am a beginner in azure databricks notebook. I read the docs that in the azure databricks notebook, there should be a Repo in the sidebar. But in one of my notebooks, I didn't find it. Do you know why? Is it because of some setting on purpose?[image]

Comment: Hey @Zhiqiang Yang, did you find Repo section when you click on Search in sidebar or same issue?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT, I clicked on Search in sidebar and no Repos shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when Repos aren't enabled in your Databricks workspace:

[image]

Ask your administrator to enable it:

[image]